# How to use BoxCox transformation in the caret package in R?

Tags: r, r-caret

```
#univariate transformations to solve skewness(boxcox)
library(caret)
describe(data_numeric)
trans_data <- preProcess(data_numeric, method = c("BoxCox"))

> dput(head(data_numeric))
structure(list(age = c(56, 57, 37, 40, 56, 45), duration = c(261, 
149, 226, 151, 307, 198), EmpVarRt = c(1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 
1.1), ConPrIdx = c(93.994, 93.994, 93.994, 93.994, 93.994, 93.994
), ConConIdx = c(-36.4, -36.4, -36.4, -36.4, -36.4, -36.4), euribor3m = c(4.857, 
4.857, 4.857, 4.857, 4.857, 4.857), campaign = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1), pdays = c(999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999), previous = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), nr_employed = c(5191, 5191, 5191, 5191, 5191, 
5191)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to transform the numeric variables in data_numeric using boxcox transformation in caret package, in order to solve skewness and identify outliers. R gave me an error

> "Error in predict.BoxCoxTrans(bc[[i]], x[, i]) : newdata should be a numeric vector"

Can anyone help me with this?

Add: output of dput(head(data_numeric))

Comment: Please share a part of your `data_numeric` using `dput(data_numeric)` or `dput(head(data_numeric))`.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, I added the R output in my original question, thanks!

Comment: If I run `preProcess(data_numeric, method = c("BoxCox"))` together with your shown data, there is no error.

Comment: Emmm I never used dput function before, is its output part of my data or?

Comment: Yeah and when I run it with dput(head(data_numeric)), there's no error, but having same error with dput(data_numeric).

Comment: How many rows does your `data_numeric` have? Perhaps there is a problem with missing values in one column.

Comment: there are 41188 rows and no missing values

Comment: Does `sapply(data_numeric, typeof)` return `double` for every colum?

Comment: yes double for each column

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: It's fine! thanks for your help!! This is just a strange data set....